# How to keep scroll position when pressing back button in angular 13, I'm already using RouteReuseStrategy

Tags: angular, scroll

I have a long list of items inside a big scrollable div. Each time when a user click on an item to see the details of item then click the back button, it starts at the very top of the div. It is not user friendly to our users. Any ways to let the browser scroll to the previous position when pressing the back button?

Thank you very much!

[I'm already know the position of scroll but i couldn't set it. Always the position of scroll reset to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Uik.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The long list of items, are they loaded on back button press ?

Comment: No, they don't. It loads in child app-command-items .I found the reason why it doesn't set scroll at first time. In fact, It sets scroll before the items are being loaded so i added set timeout and it works

Comment: Like this : filter((events) => events instanceof NavigationStart || events instanceof NavigationEnd) ).subscribe(event => { if (event instanceof NavigationStart && event.url !== this.lastRoute) { this.lastRoute = this.router.url this.lastPosition = this.commandeList.nativeElement.scrollTop } else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd && event.url === this.lastRoute) { setTimeout(()=>{this.commandeList.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.lastPosition; },350); } })

Answer (score 0):

Add `scrollPositionRestoration: "enabled"` to your routing module as option.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  scrollPositionRestoration: "enabled", //--> add this
})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```